# Make a copy of an iteration

Tags: python, iteration

I am creating a list of game objects. I'm attempting to take these basic Iterations from the objects_list and putting them into [[][][][][][]] lists within a list to correspond to the 6x6 game grid.

```
All.objects_list.extend([Inert("dirt","filthy, dirty, dirt"),
Inert("trees","tall spindly trees"),
Inert("rocks","scatterd rocks"),])
```

I just get an error

*Inert' object does not support indexing*

```
for i in range(0,37):
    for item in All.objects_list:
        All.objects.append(item[i])
```

Is there a way I can place into, remove and interact with a list iterated items for each of my 36 rooms?

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/EF18EB50-22D0-4A6B-A54C-1F9803851E30/Pythonista3/Documents/Text
> Adventures/ADVvX.py", line 603, in <module>
>     All.objects.append(item[i]) TypeError: 'Inert' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Can you show the exact exception traceback?

Comment: Well `object_list` is a list of `Inert` _objects_. Inside the loop `item` is an _object_ not a _list_. What do expect from `item[i]`. Here `item` is just an instance of `Inert`.Say, `x = Inert("dirt","filthy, dirty, dirt")`. Now what do you expect `x[1]` to return?

Comment: I'm trying to get [i] to create a nested list for every room using i

Comment: What is `All.objects_list`? List with single dimension and 36 slots? Or 2 dimensions, 6 x 6?

Comment: I have a game board of a 6x6 with nested lists and I want to have the items stored with 36 nested lists that I can call with [0][item].....[36][item] and align using [player_y+6][player_x]. Right now my objects list is just []